# Making a development and deployment environment for blockchain applications. Tools needed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, ibm-blockchain

I would like to learn a little bit from Blockchain and I need to make an university task based on this question.

The main idea is to conceptually learn about what should an environment need to develop and deploy the blockchain solutions.

My problem is that I am not a developer and I am an industrial engineer. This is my first experience with something like this and I have no idea about this stuff. I read a lot about this on github sites about some of these platforms, mostly Hyperledger Fabric and Ethereum. I am very confused about what I have read is the need of an application generator, a code editor, containers such as dockers, something about APIs and REST servers, CLI tools, Frameworks, clients, libraries as node.js or npm...

I know how Blockchain works but I do not have an idea of how to create it and start with it.
So I need a list of the vital tools because I did not find anything well explained for a beginner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking the Hyperledger "Introduction to Blockchain Development" course. It's free, unless you want a certificate.

https://www.edx.org/course/blockchain-for-business-an-introduction-to-hyperledger-technologies

Hyperledger has multiple blockchain platforms, such as Sawtooth or Fabric. They are all permissioned blockchains and do not use cryptocurrency.

If you want to use a public blockchain that uses cryptocurrency, consider Ethereum.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. I will check it sure. Actually, I've made some introduction courses from IBM to Hyperledger and some from edX to learn about Blockchain so I know how it works. My main problem is defining what tools an environment need, just because I don't have technical knowledge in this field... I would love to learn about it, but the deadline of the task I mentioned is in two weeks.  After that I would carry on learning